# Como retornar mensagem de erro com a API

Tags: c#

Bom dia,
estou a tentar retornar mensagem de erro quando algo de errado acontece na api, já fiz isso para todas as request da api, mas para uma em específica da erro, a action que mostra todos os users que é `IEnumerable`.

aqui esta o meu código;

```
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<User> GetAll()
    {
        try
        {
            return userRepository.GetAll();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return StatusCode(500,ex.InnerException.Message);
        }

    }
```

Como retorno o erro? o meu 
`return StatusCode(500,ex.InnerException.Message);` dá o seguinte erro

`Cannot implicitly convert type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ObjectResult' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<API.Models.User>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) [API]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para resolver o seu problema basta alterar o retorno na assinatura para `ActionResult<IEnumerable<User>>`. Demais alterações não são mais necessárias.

Cabe ressaltar que [essa opção só está disponível a partir da versão 2.1](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/action-return-types?view=aspnetcore-3.1#actionresultt-type).

```cs
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<IEnumerable<User>> GetAll()
    {
        try
        {
            return userRepository.GetAll();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return StatusCode(500,ex.InnerException.Message);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Altere a assinatura do método para retornar um `IActionResult` e coloque seu retorno dos usuários dentro do método [Ok](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.web.http.apicontroller.ok?view=aspnetcore-2.2).

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult GetAll()
{
    try
    {
        return Ok(userRepository.GetAll());
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return StatusCode(500, ex.InnerException.Message);
    }
}
```